# Magento AddAttributeToSelect() on custom added attribute (observer)

Tags: observer-pattern, magento-1.5, magento

I have set up an observer on `catalog_product_collection_load_after` and the following code is called:

```
<?php
class Drench_Admindetails_Model_Observer {
    public function loadAfter($observer){
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('admin_id', Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getUserId());
        foreach($collection as $item) {
            fb($item->getAdminId()); //fb() is a firebug call
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am filtering the collection on `admin_id`, which I created through the following setup script (namespace/module/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Setup.php).

```
<?php

class Drench_Admindetails_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{
    public function getDefaultEntities()
    {
        return array(
            'catalog_product'                        => array (
                'entity_model'                       => 'catalog/product',
                'attribute_model'                    => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
                'table'                              => 'catalog/product',
                'additional_attribute_table'         => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection'        => 'catalog/product_attribute_collection',
                'attributes'                         => array (
                    'admin_id'                       => array (
                        'group'                      => '',
                        'label'                      => '',
                        'type'                       => 'int',
                        'input'                      => '',
                        'default'                    => '0',
                        'class'                      => '',
                        'backend'                    => '',
                        'frontend'                   => '',
                        'source'                     => '',
                        'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'visible'                    => false,
                        'required'                   => false,
                        'user_defined'               => false,
                        'searchable'                 => false,
                        'filterable'                 => false,
                        'comparable'                 => false,
                        'visible_on_front'           => false,
                        'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                        'unique'                     => false
                    )
               )
           )
        );
    }
}
```

This attribute stores the admin that added the product.
However, the collection is not filtered on `admin_id`, and in the `foreach()` loop in the observer method, it returns `NULL` rather than the actual `admin_id` it should return.

Any ideas on why its not working?

Comment: admin_id is an array? ... as it is in your config?

Comment: No, admin_id is an `int`, it's a Magento EAV attribute which I've added to catalog_product.

Comment: Not that I know of, it's been added as an `int` I think (hence why type = int in the array), I'm quite new to magento development, so correct me if I'm wrong, I was following this tutorial: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot filter a collection after it has been loaded. Use the event `catalog_product_collection_load_before` instead. If you attempt to iterate the collection at this point it may call the same event and start an infinite recursion, which would be bad.

The `admin_id` attribute probably won't be added to the selected columns for product lists unless the attribute has `used_in_product_listing` set to `true`. You might also be successful with using `$collection->`[`addAttributeToSelect('admin_id')`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection.html#addAttributeToSelect) in the same before load event.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that this is only for the admin backend (manage products), but because I had used after instead of before, it wouldn't show it. Works absolutely fine now! Thanks very much!